# REGEXP - Select only rows that contain letters and full stop

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to write this query, I need to select the rows where a column has only letters (a-z) and a full stop.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (c1 REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z\.]') = 0
```

This one would usually work in PHP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z.]+$'
```

The anchor `^` and `$` ensure that you are matching the entire string and not part of it. Next the character class `[a-zA-Z.]` matches a single upper/lower case letter or a period. The `+` is the quantifier for one or more repetitions of the previous sub-regex, so in this case it allows us to match one or more of either a period or a upper/lower case letter.

[More info on regex usage in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: The key point here being that you don't need to escape the `.` inside a `[]` chacter class and you must anchor with `^$`.